# ListView adapter does not show all requested data

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i fill listview with data from local sqlite database. from my current query I want to get the foodname and protein, have set it in the Textview , adapter and query to get this data, but it only return only the name not the protein.

Here is the adapter class:

```
public class Db_listView_Adapter extends CursorAdapter {
public Db_listView_Adapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.db_list, viewGroup, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView foodName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodNameInListView);
    TextView foodProtein = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodProteinInListView);
    TextView foodCarbs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodCarbsInListView);
    TextView foodFat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodFatsInListView);
    TextView foodCalories = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodCaloriesInListView);
    TextView foodFibers = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodFibersInListView);
    TextView foodVitA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodVitAInListView);
    TextView foodVitB = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodVitBInListView);
    TextView foodCalcium = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodCalciumInListView);
    TextView foodMagnesium = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodMagnesiumInListView);

    String foodNameString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_FoodName"));
    String foodProteinString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_FoodProtein"));

    foodName.setText(foodNameString);
    foodProtein.setText(foodProteinString);
}
```

}

Here is the xml for the layout of the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodNameInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodProteinInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodCarbsInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodFatsInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodCaloriesInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodFibersInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodVitAInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodVitBInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodCalciumInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/foodMagnesiumInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here I try to get the data from the database and fill the listview:

```
public class Db_fragment extends Fragment {
View view;
ListView listView;
Db_listView_Adapter db_listView_adapter;


public Db_fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.db_fragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dbView);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final MyDatabaseOpenHelper mDbHelper = new MyDatabaseOpenHelper(view.getContext());


    final EditText foodName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameForDb);
    Button enterData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.enterData);
    Button showData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.showData);
    final TextView errorTextNameMissing = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.errorTextNameMissing);

    showData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (foodName.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {

                errorTextNameMissing.setText("");
                SQLiteDatabase myDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                String[] projection = {TableFoodMacros.FoodMacros._ID, TableFoodMacros.FoodMacros.FOOD_NAME, TableFoodMacros.FoodMacros.FOOD_PROTEIN};
                String rawQuery = "SELECT _ID, _Foodname , _FoodProtein FROM FoodMacros where _FoodName = " + "'" + foodName.getText().toString() + "'";

                Cursor c = myDb.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
                if(c.getCount() == 0){
                    Intent goToSaveFood = new Intent(getActivity(),Save_Food.class);
                    goToSaveFood.putExtra("FoodName", foodName.getText().toString());
                    myDb.close();
                    startActivity(goToSaveFood);
                }else {

                    db_listView_adapter = new Db_listView_Adapter(view.getContext(), c);
                    listView.setAdapter(db_listView_adapter);
                    myDb.close();
                }
            } else {
                errorTextNameMissing.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.errorTextNameMissing));
            }

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `_FoodProtein` column has a non-empty string?

Comment: i add _FoodName and _FoodProtein before i try to retrieve it from the data base. I retrieve the name, but not the data i have entered in _FoodProtein

Comment: Have you tried to [debug](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) your application to see what is going on?

Comment: Can you debug the cursor data in bindView() method before setting the food name and protein in actual TextView, so it will find whether it is data problem or View problem.

Comment: One more thing I have noticed you raw query has column field name as _Foodname and inside your binView method it is  _FoodName. as per code should not give the FoodName value as well.

Comment: any reason for not using `SimpleCursorAdapter` ?

Comment: I have no problems with _FoodName  ( for column field name sqlite is case insensitive http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_syntax.htm)

Didnt know SimpleCursorAdapter exists , will check it ( new to programming and Android)

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter` is as simple as [this](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

Answer (score 0):

So i found that the problem was in the activity that add data in the DB, i was doing in onCreate instead of onClick... ;x